# file download progress in javascript

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I am working on a javascript function which downloads a file using XMLHttpRequest and assigns to a variable. I have been asked to provide a status of the download progress (like providing % of download).

I calculated the percent downloaded using getResponseHeader("Content-Length") (which is the amount of data downloaded)  and the  total download file size (this is always constant). This works in FF and Chrome, but not in IE(argh!!).

I am aware IE does not supply the getResponseHeader("Content-Length") while readyState=3, so I have been searching for alternatives.

Has any one found a solution for this?

I came across the idea of polling the download request with a second ajax request to the server. I am not sure how this will be possible given that HTTP requests are stateless and sending a second request will be treated as a new call by the application.
I don't want to go in the direction of saving some variable in the server and reading it.

Any suggestions will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this: (coffeescript)

```
xhr.onprogress = (e) ->
    # show progress and size of file.
    console.log "#{Math.round(e.loaded/e.total)*100}% completed"
```